# Obsolete PDB Files generated by DDK

Tags: c++, pdb-files, wdk

I have a very simple application in VS.NET 2002 (C++) that calls a function from a DLL. The DLL is built with WINDDK and MSC_OPTIMIZATION is set to /Od /Oi

When I try to step into the exported function from the DLL it fails. I then tried to load the symbols from the PDB file generated by WINDDK (XP Checked environment), but I get the "pdb format is obsolete" message.

The PDB file is "Microsoft C/C++ MSF 7.00"

Can VS.NET 2002 read this PDB file, ie. is it perhaps to old/new ?

Regards
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

7.00 is the Visual C++ version number for the original VS.NET so I would expect the debugger to be able to use PDB files generated by it.

I *think* you also have to provide something like /Zi to the compiler and the appropriate switch to the linker to get PDB debug symbols.